# Get Name Of Array Object In JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I want names like salem,madurai from this json

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "DisplayList": [
        {
            "AVINASHI": [
                "gmail@com",
                "gmail@hp.com"
            ]
        },
        {
            "AVINASHI": [
                "gmail@com",
                "gmail@hp.com"
            ]
        },
        {
            "ERNAVOOR": [
                "sri@gmail.com",
                "sri@gmail.com"
            ]
        },
        {
            "ERNAVOOR": [
                "sri@gmail.com",
                "sri@gmail.com"
            ]
        },
        {
            "HYDCURD": [
                "sri@gmail.com"
            ]
        },
        {
            "KANCHIPURAM": [
                "sri@gmail.com"
            ]
        },
        {
            "KEELKATTLAI": [
                "sri@gmail.com"
            ]
        },
        {
            "MADURAI": [
                "sri@gmail.com",
                "sri2@gmail.com"
            ]
        },
        {
            "MADURAI": [
                "sri@gmail.com",
                "sri2@gmail.com"
            ]
        },
        {
            "SALEM": [
                "gmail@hp.com",
                "gmail@hp.com",
                "gmail@hp1.com"
            ]
        },
        {
            "SALEM": [
                "gmail@hp.com",
                "gmail@hp.com",
                "gmail@hp1.com"
            ]
        },
        {
            "SALEM": [
                "gmail@hp.com",
                "gmail@hp.com",
                "gmail@hp1.com"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Geeze, that is really bad use of JSON. Do you have control over the output at all?

Comment: If yes, you should have something like this: http://pastebin.com/bbWv1n8n

Comment: @Marty: Why not just like http://pastebin.com/jxLpP4eT?

Comment: @Bergi I feel like it's beneficial to be able to say `data.list[0].name` rather than having to make a loop and then store all the keys as names somewhere.

Comment: @Marty: Well, it would be just `Object.keys(data.list)` instead of `data.list.map(function(x){return x.name;})` :-)

Comment: @Bergi You've gone outside of my realm of understanding; I like to keep things simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var List = JSONObject['DisplayList'];
for(var i=0;i<List.length;i++)
{
    for(var key in List[i])
    {
        console.log(key); //will print names
        console.log(List[i][key]);//will print array of email
    }
}
```

Assumed you have the JSON data in variable `JSONObject`

Answer (score 2):

```
var obj = { status:'success', DisplayList: [{...}, {...}]} // your object

var l = obj.DisplayList.length,
    result = [];

while (l--){
    result = result.concat(Object.keys(obj.DisplayList[l]));
}

console.log(result.join(", "));
```

This approach uses `Object.keys` which is meant to enumerate the object properties without including the prototype properties. It is only IE9+ though so we still need a plugin: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Compatibility

Comment: `concat` does not mutate the array.

Comment: + Good catch. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for(var i in json.DisplayList) //Gets Array
    for(var k in json.DisplayList[i]) // Get object on 'i'th index of the DisplayList Array
        console.log(k); //Get the key of that object.
```

Comment: Please don't use `for..in` to iterate over arrays. It picks up non-numeric properties (such as functions you add to the prototype) as well, and the iteration order is not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks but what about if type is checked in the inner loop? e.g. typeof json.DisplayList[i] == "object";

Comment: While this will catch functions added to the prototype, if someone adds an object to the prototype, it will still be picked up by the iteration. `hasOwnProperty` fares better, but you still have no guaranteed iteration order, it still picks up non-numeric properties added to the array itself (not a worry if it's a freshly parsed JSON) and it's unneccessarily long-winded.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
var DisplayList = JSONObject['DisplayList'];
var NamesList = [];
for(var i=0; i<DisplayList.length; i++)
{
    for(var keyName in List[i])
    {
        if(NamesList.indexOf(keyName) >= 0)
        {
          NamesList.push(keyName);
        }
    }
}
console.log(NamesList); //Output: ['AVINASHI','ERNAVOOR','HYDCURD',...] 
//Not the names will not repeat.. the array will have unique values
```